# Surround selected text with images with span

Tags: jquery, html

I have the div, that contains text and images.

```
<div>
    Some text
    <img src="image.jpg">
     More text
 </div>
```

I need to surround selected text with span tag, I know how to do it with simple text, but I don't know how to do it, when there are images inside div.
Is there a way to do it?

I need to change the source code, not just text, so that i could add some css styles to selected text.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're requesting and what you want to achieve. If you just want to put text into a span, do it. you're not restricted to a single span

Comment: Then what was your OUTPUT??

Comment: Please see provided/updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you would like to use a client technology (here: jQuery) to modify the DOM.

If you want everything wrapped in one span, then use wrapAll():

```
$( "div" )
  .contents()
  .wrapAll( "<span>" );
```

If you want only text nodes wrapped in the span, then do some filtering:

```
$( "div" )
  .contents()
  .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
  .wrapAll( "<span>" );
```

At last, if you need every node wrapped in its own span, use wrap() instead wrapAll(). You may combine that with filtering as well.

**EDIT**

If you need to work with marked text, you can combine this with solution to this question: [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

I'd say something like this should work:

```
function getSelectionObj() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    }
}

$("button").click(function (){
    var o = getSelectionObj();
    if(o.anchorNode == null)
        return;

    var $node1 = $(o.anchorNode);
    var $node2 = $(o.focusNode);

    var $content = $node1.nextUntil($node2).andSelf();

    $content.wrapAll( "<span>" );
});
```

Comment: No, I don't nedd to wrap all the text, i just need to wrap selected text.

Comment: Not exactly, but i found the way to do it in another question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<div>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <img src="image.jpg">
     <span>More text</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: he want the span append with jquery using wrap